# Attribute Error: object has no attribute error -- subclassing GUI PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I added a new modal Dialog which will ask for a password whenever the user wants to delete rows. I created the GUI with Qt Designer. I can't call the inventoryTable in my GUI.

Everytime I call **secureDelete** function, an Attribute Error arises saying "'MainWindow_ui' object has no attribute 'inventoryTable'".

Can anyone tell me how I add other UIs properly and also be able to avoid this attribute errors in the future?

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.db = Database()
        self.model = Model(self)
        self.ui = MainWindow_ui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.removeItem.clicked.connect(lambda: self.start_Secure())
        self.ui.removeItem.setShortcut("Del")

    def start_Secure(self):
        self.accessForm = confirmDialog(self)
        self.accessForm.show()

class confirmDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(confirmDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = Model()
        self.access_ui = Ui_Access()
        self.access_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui = MainWindow_ui()

        self.access_ui.username.returnPressed.connect(self.secureDelete)
        self.access_ui.password.returnPressed.connect(self.secureDelete)
        self.access_ui.confirmButton.clicked.connect(self.secureDelete)

    def secureDelete(self):
        members = {'user': 'password'}
        username = self.access_ui.username.text()
        password = self.access_ui.password.text()

        if username in members:
            enteredPass = members.get(username)
            indices = self.ui.inventoryTable.selectionModel().selectedRows()
            if password == enteredPass:
                for index in sorted(indices):
                    self.model.removeRow(index.row())
            else:
                self.model.revertRow(indices)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes generated by Qt Designer provide the `setupUi()` method to create the design elements so that in your case you have not called it, and consequently never created the `inventoryTable`, but even passing it using that function would not achieve your goal since you would be creating a new instance.

In your particular case as you have passed to self as parent of `confirmDialog`:

```
self.accessForm = confirmDialog(self)
```

Then you can access Main through the `parent()` method in your case do the following:

```
class confirmDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        [...]
        self.access_ui.setupUi(self)
        # self.ui = MainWindow_ui()
        [...]

    def secureDelete(self):
        [...]

        if username in members:
            enteredPass = members.get(username)
            indices = self.parent().ui.inventoryTable.selectionModel().selectedRows()
            [...]
```